# How to store the address pointed to by a pointer?

Tags: pointers, go

I am trying to create a map of addresses of objects that I create with the time at which it is allocated. The key is the address returned by the call to `new()`. How do I get the address returned by `new()`?

```
type T struct{a, b int }

func main(){

        var t int64 = time.Nanoseconds()
        memmap := make(map[uint8]int64)
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", t)
        var ptr *T = new(T)
        ptr.a = 1
        ptr.b = 2
        fmt.Printf("%d %d %p %T\n", ptr.a, ptr.b, ptr, ptr)
        //memmap[ptr] = t //gives error
        //var temp uint8 = ptr//gives error
}
```

Please tell me what should be the type of the key field in the map so that I can store the address returned by `new()`? I plan to use `new()` with different types, get the allocated address and map it with the creation time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the type `Pointer` from the `unsafe` package, but that is, the package name implies it, unsafe. The address itself is a opaque thing and there's only little use in actually using a address value alone for a map, better use a tuple of type and address. That's what `unsafe.Reflect` does provide you. The package `reflect` offers you the function `UnsafeAddr` and a lot more.

I suggest you read the package documentation for `reflect` and `unsafe` packages.

Answer (score 3):

Use [uintptr](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Numeric_types), an unsigned integer large enough to store the uninterpreted bits of a pointer value, as the memory map key type.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

type T struct{ a, b int }

func main() {
    memmap := make(map[uintptr]int64)

    pT := new(T)
    memmap[uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pT))] = time.Nanoseconds()
    pT.a = 1
    pT.b = 2
    fmt.Printf("%d %d %p %T\n", pT.a, pT.b, pT, pT)

    pI := new(int)
    memmap[uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pI))] = time.Nanoseconds()
    *pI = 42
    fmt.Printf("%d %p %T\n", *pI, pI, pI)

    fmt.Printf("\n%T\n", memmap)
    for k, v := range memmap {
        fmt.Printf("%x: %d\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 0xf8400001f8 *main.T
42 0xf8400001f0 *int

map[uintptr] int64
f8400001f0: 1306837191421330000
f8400001f8: 1306837191421293000
```